# How do you add new rows to a MySql table?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an application that is deployed to Heroku and using the JawsDB add on to replicate my local MySQL database. I recently updated a table in the local MySQL database (Plans) to include two new rows, `'plan_dates'` and `'plan_times'`, but the hosted JawsDB did not automatically sync with the changes made on my local connection.

I opened up the JawsDB database on MySQL using the connection string provided by Heroku to try and add in the rows manually. These are the rows in the Plan table that I am trying to edit:
[database rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1nLd.png)

I've searched online, but I cannot find any resources on how to add new (empty) rows to a table on MySQL -- all I can find online are references to 'INSERT INTO', which inserts specific values into rows, but that's not exactly what I'm looking to do. I did try running INSERT INTO as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Plans (plan_dates, plan_times)
VALUES(NULL, NULL);
```

but then I ran into the following error:

> Unknown column 'plan_dates' in 'field list'

Am I missing a very simple command or is there any other way to add new empty rows to a table that has already been created in MySQL?

Comment: The word you're looking for is `column` not `row`. You change the table structure (and add columns) with ALTER TABLE

Comment: Read https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, The `columns` are not exist in your table and you must add it to the table using `ALTER Table` query.

Syntax would be

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD [COLUMN] column_name column_definition [FIRST|AFTER existing_column];
```

So your query should be

```
ALTER TABLE Plans 
ADD COLUMN plan_dates Date AFTER UserId,
ADD COLUMN plan_times TIME AFTER UserId;
```

And you can use `INSERT` statement to add new empty rows.

```
INSERT INTO Plans (id, start_date, end_date, maxMins, totalMins, UserId, plan_dates, plan_times) VALUES(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```